# Executar um programa rdp por um aplicativo PHP

Tags: php

Teria como executar um programa rdp atraves de um site php ?

tentei

```
echo exec("start \\192.168.1.233\Teste\Apps\BRAVOS.rdp") or die("ERROU");
```

e

```
system("\\192.168.1.233\Teste\Apps\BRAVOS.rdp");
```

mais somente carega e volta para a pagina que eu chamei o comando o aplicativo nao abre.

é possivel abrir dessa forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode criar um arquivo .bat, apontando para seu programa. No PHP, use esse código:

```
$handle = popen('meu_bat.bat', 'r');
$read = fread($handle, 2096);
pclose($handle);
```

E dentro do `meu_bat.bat` coloque a chamada para seu programa:

```
START MEU_PROGRAMA.EXE
```

[Fonte POPEN](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.popen.php)

Comment: bom ao colocar                                                                                  $handle = popen('bravos.bat', 'r');
$read = fread($handle, 8192);
pclose($handle);                                                                                      em um arquivo php para abrir e só apontar um link para ele correto ? pois quando executo o bat o programa abre mais quando aponto para um arquivo onde contem o codigo acima nada ocorre